# Handling wallet expiry on Autonomous Database?

Tags: ssl, wallet, mtls, oracle-autonomous-db

Is there is any way to get around the SSL certificates in the wallets expiring, having looked at the expiry date that is in the wallet.zip README file as well as the orapki utility.

If one cannot get around SSL certificates expiring what is the recommended way of managing SSL certificates and their expiry?

Answer (score 2):

Autonomous Database takes security seriously, so there's no way to get around an encrypted, secure connection and you will need to download new wallets before their expiry date. You can have multiple wallets with different expirations concurrently, so there is no service interruption.

Depending on your application, you may also consider enabling mTLS to go walletless, which we released recently! Read [Todd Sharp's post about this](https://blogs.oracle.com/developers/post/securely-connecting-to-autonomous-db-without-a-wallet-using-tls) as well as the [ADB documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/support-tls-mtls-authentication.html#GUID-3F3F1FA4-DD7D-4211-A1D3-A74ED35C0AF5) for more detail.

Ref: I am a product manager on the Oracle Autonomous Database :)